# How to deserialize from empty JSON file to Java Object using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I have a json file(a.json) with contents as below:-

```
{
"name" : "ABC",
"id": "1234"
}
```

I try to deserialize to Student class using the below code:-

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.readValue(new File("a.json"), Student.class)
```

where Student class is :-

```
class Student {

    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

This code works fine. But the problem is suppose a.json file is empty when i try to deserialize below code raises EOFException with message as "No content to map to Object due to end of input"

```
Student student =objectMapper.readValue(new File("a.json"), Student.class)
```

How do handle this? Is there a way i can configure object mapper so that it doesn't raise an exception and just returns null?

Comment: Try adding `objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, true);`

Answer (score 1):

Would

```
try{
    Student student =objectMapper.readValue(new File("a.json"), Student.class);
} catch(EOFException e) {
    Student student = new Student(null, null);
}
```

Achieve what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you. This can be used but i wanted to know isthere some flag which can be configured on object mapper, something similar to  objectMapper.configure(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true).